# Windows Service High performance and Scalability

Tags: c#, windows-services

Please help me out of this scenario of windows service implementation. Actually, what i need is , i have to fetch the images from the axis camera through its api using HTTPWEBREQUESTS, and store it into the database.

Note : I am able to fetch the images from the axis camera API through HTTPWEBREQUESTS, and the solution is good for one camera through windows service.

Complete Scenario : The images should be stored every minute from the camera that is every minute an image should be fetched from the api and stored in the database in the binary format.Every image should be is about 100Kb and there are 200 or more such cameras whose minute by minute history is to be maintained in the database so that it may be viewed by the user.

I am not getting a scalable and high performance solution for this kind of implementations. Moreover the same database is being accessed by my web application.

Thanks
Amit Narula

Comment: Sorry, bu we lack a crystal ball. What exactly is your problem? You tell us all the time things work, then saying you wont get a scalable and high performance solution but you never define what scalable means or high perforamance means in your context. What is your problem?

Comment: Storing a 100k image once a minute should not even tickle a server - not sure how "high performance and scalability" applies to this. You need to be **much** more specific about the problem.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your views..Let me explain this...Basically what i think is, if i make HTTPWEBREQUEST in large number of cameras scenario then, it may make my windows service very slow and consume large set of system resources (server where i want to install the service), as more than 200 HTTPWEBREQUESTS per minute causing insertion in my database through windows service, so is there any way that i can make that functionality with high performance?

Answer (score 1):

Not that 100kb should cause much of a problem but maybe you could put a max limit on how many could update at onetime and have the others wait till there is a open slot keeping all 20 from updateing at one time.